# redux calculator multiplication and division are not working

Tags: redux, react-redux

As a Redux noob I am experimenting with React and Redux, trying to understand the deeper part of this complicated framework in combination with state container. In the link below you will understand that the multiplication and division does not work like the addiction and subtraction button. Not sure how I should fix the multiplication and division button, so it works like a real calculator. Anyone who could help me to the right direction?

When clicking on division for example gives me the following messages: infinity and NaN. Not sure how to avoid that.

https://codesandbox.io/s/xjlp0j1k3w

When I click 3 i will get this in the console.log --> 0 3 false

Then click on 9 the console.log will output the following number 0 9 false, but how to I store the second number of the first click which is 3 in this case, and divide that by the second number of the second click (number 9). So at the end we have the sum 3 / 9 = ....

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the logic of your reducer.

```
return {
        ...state,
        inputValue: 0,
        resultValue: state.resultValue / state.inputValue,
        showingResult: true
      };
```

You're setting the inputValue to zero. When you divide the resultValue with it, the result is infnity. On the other hand, multiplying anything with zero results in zero. You could try setting the inputValue to 1 for the DIVIDE and the TIME cases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This avoids the earlier mentioned error, but unfortunately it is not the proper working solution.